# Why does if a = = ("B" or "C") not take effect when a==“ C” even if I use parentheses?

Tags: python

```
sum=0
count=0

while True:

    inp=input("Enter a number:")
    if inp==("done" or "Done"):
         break
    value=eval(inp)
    sum+=value
    count+=1
  
print(sum/count)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Up40.jpg)

Comment: `inp in ("done", "Done")`

Comment: What do you think should be the result of `("done"or"Done")` by itself? What actually is the result, when you test it? Do you see why this causes a problem for your logic?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Comment: I know that usage. But I wonder why this won’t take effect

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Python's `or` operation returns the value that makes the overall expression `True`. And the parentheses group the operation so that it is resolved before the comparison. So, `("done" or "Done")` always resolves to `"done"`. Your statement is equivalent to `if inp == "done"`.

Comment: The duped answer isn't the right one for this question. The difference here is why it works when `inp` is "done" but not when its "Done".

Comment: Important side note: Don't use `eval` ever again until you read and understood [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html). If you want to convert a string to a number you can use `int` or `float`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inp == "done" or inp == "Done"`, `inp in ("done", "Done")` for a small number of options, `inp in {"done", "Done"}` for a large number of options, or `inp.lower() == "done"` if you want to accept any casing.

`"done" or "Done"` is equivalent to `"done" if "done" else "Done"`, which evaluates to `"done"`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I know these usages. But I wonder why this won’t take effect

Comment: @TianyuHe See what the value of `"done" or "Done"` is. Try experimenting with empty strings and various other values, as well as expressions with side-effects (e.g. using `print`) to improve your understanding of how the `or` operator works.